# Running Emma on Hudson results in JVM_Bind Exception

Tags: hudson, emma

I am attempting to get Emma to run with one of my jobs on Hudson.
I am using Hudson 2.2.0.  I have the Emma plugin installed.

I read a guide online, on how to configure Emma to run on Hudson - and it was as simple as adding a build step of emma:emma.  But sadly this then fails every single unit test with the below JVM_Bind issue.
Has anyone seen this before.  I have searched as hard as I can, but I am still unable to come up with a reason for this, let alone a solution.
I have checked using netstat -a and nothing is using the port mentioned below, so I am considering the possibility that this is a red herring.
I would be grateful for any help offered!

```
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Hudson\jobs\EKB\workspace\trunk\hydrocarbon-   plus\target\surefire-reports
EMMA: collecting runtime coverage data ...
EMMA: runtime controller started on port [47653] 
EMMA: collecting runtime coverage data ...
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:97)
at com.vladium.emma.rt.RTController.start(RTController.java:99)
at com.vladium.emma.rt.RT.reset(RT.java:222)
at com.vladium.emma.rt.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:540)
at com.*.application.core.types.RTNumber.$VRi(RTNumber.java)
at com.*.application.core.types.RTNumber.<clinit>(RTNumber.java)
at com.*.application.data.domain.datapoint.EnergyTest.<clinit>(EnergyTest.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:61)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:294)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestsFromTestCase(TestSuite.java:150)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:129)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit3Builder.java:14)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.<init>(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.createTestSet(JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.locateTestSets(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:96)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.createSuiteFromDefinition(Surefire.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1005)
```